# Migrations worked last year, but now it does not

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Migrations worked last year, but now it does not, what do I do?

**The error:**

> PM> update-database
>   Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
>   statements being applied to the target database.
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: O tipo não foi
>   resolvido para o associado
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.    em
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   em System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    em
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    em
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   em
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) The type has not been resolved to the associated
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException,MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'. 
>   PM>

**The code(partialy)**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>      
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=mySERVER;initial catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=false;uid=myID;pwd=myPWD;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
  <!-- I will show only if needed -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
  <!-- I will show only if needed -->
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!-- I will show only if needed -->
    </modules>

    <handlers>

       <!-- I will show only if needed -->
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
  <!-- I will show only if needed -->
  </runtime>
  <system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
    <!-- I will show only if needed -->
   </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Can you supply a translation of _O tipo não foi resolvido para o associado_ ?

Comment: oh , sorry for that :)

Comment: check this out, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806753/error-while-running-update-database-in-mvc5

Comment: @DavidOesterreich Now i get the error The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

Comment: Is that the inner exception? If not can you please share ...seems like a login failure.

Comment: @DavidOesterreich i need to change something in my code after update my connector?

Comment: If I use mysql workbench instead of sql server in my conection string?

Comment: I resolved the problem :)


Download xampp and mysql workbench
Start mysql in xampp;   
Starded a new connection in local host
 Created  database "teste" in mysql
Changed my conection string to

    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;initial catalog=teste;User Id=root;"  providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>

 6. And finally in the console i put: 

    

update-database

This works !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your only connection string in the config file, is pointing to a server with "System.Data.SqlClient" as the only provider;
...And the stacktrace cries about MySQL.

Im guessing that you need to provide one that supports MySQL.

I will note though, that i havent worked with multiple providers in the same project :)